# Python projects dependency manage

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependencies

I have two python projects, both are completely independent of each other(consider one is core project and other is implementation project and two independent
teams are working).

Now other team zipped(core.zip) the core project and shared the zip file with us. We want to use all the python scripts(and obviously all the functions inside) in core.zip in my implementation project.
Any suggestions on how to import zip file and use all the scripts inside zip in my new project.

Below is the structure of both the projects.

```
core_project
|---src
|---|---folder1
|       |--- file1.py
|       |--- file2.py
|       |--- file3.py
|---|---folder2
|       |--- file4.py
|       |--- file5.csv
|       |--- file6.ini
|---Makefile


impl_project
|---src
|----|---main_file.py
|----|---script1.py
|---Makefile
```

Tried something like below, didn't work

```
1

sys.path.insert(0, 'core.zip')
from src.folder1.file1 import fun1 # giving me error here

2

importer = zipimport.zipimporter('core.zip')
res = importer.find_module('file.py') # error
```

Any suggestions how to use/import core.zip(all the scripts init) in implementation project?

Comment: Put everything on Git and add the core project as a submodule where you need it.